# Select Range of months under where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables and I am joining these three table on one column field `Account_Number`. I have another field in these three tables called `Month` type `nvarchar(20)`, inside that column months names inserted as `(January, March , April,...)`.

I need to get A `Year-To-Date` value,  by selecting a range of months (From January) until the current month (November). I tried to cast that month column to `Datetime` type. But it didn't work, even I tried to convert the month name to Month number, even that wouldn't help.

Any idea how I can write this query.

Note: I cannot change or play with month column at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select month
    from months
    where CONVERT(datetime,'1-'+month+'-2012') <= GETDATE()
```